# NSUserDefaults: storing struct/class with only property list compliant types, in a readable format

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults, plist, codable

Suppose a dictionary is stored in UserDefaults according to the following code:

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(["name": "A preset", "value": 1], forKey: "preset")
```

The plist that results from running this command is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>preset</key>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>A preset</string>
        <key>value</key>
        <integer>1</integer>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Now, consider this data should be represented by the following struct:

```
struct Preset: Codable {
    var name: String
    var value: Int
}
```

I'd like to call the following code and get the same results as above (data stored in the plist using exactly the same layout):

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(Preset(name: "A preset", value: 1), forKey: "preset")
```

Unfortunately this results in an error:

```
Attempt to set a non-property-list object
TableViewToUserDefaults.Preset(name: "A preset", value: 1)
as an NSUserDefaults/CFPreferences value for key preset
```

How can I achieve this, keeping the same plist layout, and if possible in a generic way? (i.e. one which works for any struct consisting of properties that can be encoded in a plist, without hardcoding the struct's properties such as `name` and `value` in this case)

Comment: Your own answer to this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54381536/mapping-a-dictionary-to-an-array-of-structs-in-swift) contains the solution.

Comment: The extension in question requires me to call `encode()` rather than `set(:forKey:)`. This is an issue when using bindings, since they call `set(:forKey:)`

Comment: As I said in one of my comments it's more suitable to save the struct as raw `Data` rather than encode it and then decode it as Property List.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following extension to UserDefaults solves the problem, and I didn't generalize it for lack of time, but it may be possible:

```
extension UserDefaults {
    func set(_ preset: Preset, forKey key: String) {
        set(["name": preset.name, "value": preset.value], forKey: key)
    }
}
```

This can work on arrays as well:

```
extension UserDefaults {
    func set(_ presets: [Preset], forKey key: String) {
        let result = presets.map { ["name":$0.name, "value":$0.value] }
        set(result, forKey: key)
    }
}
```

While `UserDefaults.standard.set(:forKey:)` is what the question was about, my goal was actually to get it working with Cocoa bindings for use with `NSArrayController`. I decided to subclass `NSArrayController` as follows (see comment by Hamish to [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54392379/convert-swift-encodable-class-typed-as-any-to-dictionary), which was the last missing piece of the puzzle to make this generic):

```
extension Encodable {
    fileprivate func encode(to container: inout SingleValueEncodingContainer) throws {
        try container.encode(self)
    }
}

struct AnyEncodable: Encodable {
    var value: Encodable
    init(_ value: Encodable) {
        self.value = value
    }
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        try value.encode(to: &container)
    }
}

class NSEncodableArrayController: NSArrayController {
    override func addObject(_ object: Any) {
        let data = try! PropertyListEncoder().encode(AnyEncodable(object as! Encodable))
        let any = try! PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: data, options: [], format: nil)

        super.addObject(any)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a protocol-oriented way that will solve your problem.

```swift
protocol UserDefaultStorable: Codable {
  // where we store the item
  var key: String { get }
  // use to actually load/store
  func store(in userDefaults: UserDefaults) throws
  init(from userDefaults: UserDefaults) throws
}

enum LoadError: Error {
  case fail
}

// Default implementations
extension UserDefaultStorable {
  var key: String { return "key" }
  func store(in userDefaults: UserDefaults) throws {
    userDefaults.set(try JSONEncoder().encode(self), forKey: key)
  }
  init(from userDefaults: UserDefaults) throws {
    guard let data = userDefaults.data(forKey: key) else { throw LoadError.fail }
    self = try JSONDecoder().decode(Self.self, from: data)
  }
}
```

Just make any `Codable` type conform to `UserDefaultStorable` then. This approach is very useful because let's say you have another struct:

```swift
struct User: Codable {
  let name: String
  let id: Int
}
```

Instead of defining separate functions on `UserDefaults`, you just need this one-liner:

```swift
extension User: UserDefaultStorable {}
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to write a function on the Struct that converts it to a dictionary.

```
struct Preset {
     var name: String
     var value: Int

     func toDictionary() -> [String:Any] {
         return ["name": self.name, "value": self.value]
     }
}
```

Then, to save it to UserDefaults, you can simply do this:

```
let p = Preset(name: "A preset", value: 1)
UserDefaults.standard.set(p.toDictionary(), forKey: "preset")
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: While this does work, my real issue (as clarified in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54390486/523079)) is how to make this work with Cocoa bindings for `NSArrayController`.